# Delayed Write errors

Tags: c, networking, system-administration

For the past few months, we've been losing data to a Delayed Write errors.  I've experienced the error with both custom code and shrink-wrap applications.  For example, the error message below came from Visual Studio 2008 on building a solution

> Windows - Delayed Write Failed : Windows was unable
>   to save all the data for the file
>   \Vital\Source\Other\OCHSHP\Done07\LHFTInstaller\Release\LHFAI.CAB. The
>   data has been lost. This error may be caused by a failure of your
>   computer hardware or network connection. Please try to save this file
>   elsewhere.

When it occurs in Adobe, Visual Studio, or Word, for example, no harm is done.  The major problem is when it occurs to our custom applications (straight C apps that writes data in dBase files to a network share.)

From the program's perspective, the write succeeds.  It deletes the source data, and goes on to the next record.  A few minutes later, Windows pops up an error message saying that a delayed write occurred and the data was lost.

My question is, what can we do to ***help*** our networking/server teams isolate and correct the problem (read, convince them the problem is real.  Simply telling them many, many times hasn't convinced them as of yet) and do you have any suggestions of how we can write to avoid the data loss?

Comment: Writing to dBase files over network shares?  You're a braver man than I am!

Comment: @Jonathan, Legacy code, what can I say?  I would prefer writing data to our SQL server, but our solution has to work both at the shop and at 40 + hospitals around the state.    Eventually, it'll be replaced with a web-based solution.  Until then, we need to prevent data loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writes on Windows, like any modern operating system, are not actually sent to the disk until the OS gets around to it.  This is a big performance win, but the problem (as you have found) is that you cannot detect errors at the time of the write.

Every operating system that does asynchronous writes also provides mechanisms for forcing data to disk.  On Windows, the [FlushFileBuffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364439%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) or [_commit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17618685) function will do the trick.  (One is for `HANDLE`s, the other for file descriptors.)

Note that you *must* check the return value of every disk write, *and* the return value of these synchronizing functions, in order to be certain the data made it to disk.  Also note that these functions block and wait for the data to reach disk -- even if you are writing to a network server -- so they can be slow.  Do not call them until you really need to push the data to stable storage.

For more, see [fsync() Across Platforms](http://www.humboldt.co.uk/2009/03/fsync-across-platforms.html).

Comment: Thanks for the advice!  While I would like to address the underlying problems which are causing the problems, this, at least, will prevent data loss.

Answer (score 0):

You have a corrupted file system or a hard disk that is failing.  The networking/server team should scan the disk to fix the former and detect the latter. Also check the error log to see if it tells you anything. If the error log indicates that failure to write to the hardware then you need to replace the disk.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try to get our server team to look at it.  I know that they have compressed the drive in question, to avoid buying more storage.  Our office offered to buy more storage but were told "we don't have a storage problem, we have a user problem."  Over 1,000 people use that sever as their primary network share.