# System.IO is there a way to detect delayed write failure (from WebDAV)?

Tags: c#, file-io, io, webdav, mapped-drive

So I have a C# console app that goes through a huge list of files and copies missing files to a remote location using a WebDAV mapped drive.

In essence, I'm not using a custom client, I'm using windows built-in client.

`net use j: http://127.69.69.69 /user:testme pass /persistent:yes`

Everything seems to work just fine (I've increased the file size limits on the IIS 7.0 server, etc. ) EXCEPT occasionally I get a "Delayed Write Failure" popup from the OS.

My problem is that my application does not bail/throw an exception on the File.Copy() Method on the client-- How might I detect this?

I guess it's not a huge deal, but part of me wonders why no exception is thrown. It appears to move onto the next file without logging an error. My script checks if the remote file size is the same and can replace a partial file on the next cycle.

Pretty simple code where it actually copies:

```
Log("\n copying " + lf.FullName);
try
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(remotePath, localDir.Name)))
          Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(remotePath, localDir.Name));
}
catch (Exception e)
{
       Log("Cannot create remote directory " + Path.Combine(remotePath, localDir.Name) + " " + e.Message , "error");
}
try
{
    File.Copy(lf.FullName, Path.Combine(new string[] { remotePath, localDir.Name, lf.Name }), true);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
     Log("Cannot copy file to " + Path.Combine(new string[] { remotePath, localDir.Name, lf.Name }) + " " + e.Message, "error");
}
```

Comment: The machine is screwed up.  Fix the disk drive, soon.

Comment: @HansPassant did you even read the question?

Comment: @HansPassant well your response has nothing to do with the question. I know it's not a failing drive-- it is the nature of using WebDAV mounted drive that's the issue. Also, I fail to see how the comment "The machine is screwed up. Fix the disk drive, soon." would be of value to googler. Just sayin'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delayed Write errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777788/delayed-write-errors)